# On Picard's Theorem, proof and examples

Tags: complex-analysis

In my undergraduate course on complex analysis I encountered Picard's Theorem:

"*A function with an essential singularity assumes every complex number, with possibly one exception, as a value in any neighborhood of this singularity.*"

This is clearly a very faschinating result, however I am a bit confused about the "one exception" the theorem mentions. The proof of the theorem is apparently "beyond this text" as my book puts it, so no clues can be drawn from that.

There are of course examples such as $e^{1/z}$ which has an essential singularity at 0, yet never attains the value 0, but I am still left wondering about that statement. Does the one exception only appear *at* the singularity, or can it be elsewhere in the neighborhood? I am also curious to know if there is a good way to understand why the theorem is true without delving too deep into its proof which apparently is out of my reach at this level. Lastly, I would be very appreciative of any other illustrative examples of the theorem. Other than the function $e^{1/z}$, are there any other "simple", or commonly occuring functions with essential singularities?

Comment: The little Picard theorem is that if $f$ is entire and avoids $0,1$ [then $\lambda^{-1}(f(z))$ is entire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_lambda_function#Little_Picard_theorem) where $\lambda$ is analytic $\{\Im(z) > 0\}\to \Bbb{C}-\{0,1\}$. Thus $\lambda^{-1}(f(z))$ takes its values in $\Im(z) > 0$ and $\frac{1}{\lambda^{-1}(f(z))+i}$ is entire and bounded thus constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more precise statement would be: let $A$ be an open subset of $\mathbb C$, let $a\in A$, let $f\colon A\setminus\{a\}\longrightarrow\mathbb C$ be an analytic function, and let $V$ be a neighborhood of $a$ contained in $A$. Then, if $a$ is an essential singularity of $f$, $f(V\setminus\{a\})$ is either $\mathbb C$ or $\mathbb C\setminus\{w\}$ for some $w\in\mathbb C$.

Actually, it's stronger than that: the equation $f(z)=z^\star$ has infinitely many solutions in $V$, no matter how small $V$ is, for each $z^\star\in\mathbb C$, with, at most, one exception. Note that even for that exception (let us call it $w$, as above), the equation $f(z)=w$ may have solutions, but only finitely many.

And the case of $e^{1/z}$ is the archetypal example.

You shall find a very will written proof in *Complex made simple*, by one of our members, David. C. Ullrich.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This statement is more clear to me that that of my textbook. So I take it that the exception _w_ does not have to be _a_. Do you perhaps know if this fact has any special consequences, or maybe even _why_ this is? I still find it hard to "accept" this fact. I will make sure to add _Complex Made Simple_ to my reading list, it seems to cover Picard's Theorem very extensively indeed.

Comment: Yes, the exception is not $a$.

Comment: Possibly you should be explicit that it's $\exists w\forall V$, not the other way around. (Although here the two are actually equivalent, just as your stronger version about infinitely  many solutions is immediate from the apparently weaker version...) Heh, thx for the plug...